# Check for nested object property

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Let's say we have a `window` object that looks like `window.someObject.someProperty.subProperty` and we have an `if` condition where we check if `subProperty === "foo"`.

In order to avoid a `cannot read property xxx of undefined` I would have to write something like

```
if (window.someObject && window.someObject.someProperty &&  window.someObject.someProperty.subProperty === "foo") {
      // do something
}
```

Now imagine the object has more properties, it would be very long to check for all of them.

So my question is whether or not there is a faster way to perform that check without having to write all the sequence of properties.

Comment: Who about enclosing you statement in try catch?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when working with an API you should be able to anticipate what could be missing and what shouldn't. Sadly there's no shorter way to check if you want to be sure on each step. However there are preprocessors such as CoffeeScript which allow you to do this: `window.someObject?.someProperty?.subProperty`

But no vanilla way.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in [javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key/2631198#2631198) Please check their generic function

```
function checkNested(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      return false;
    }
    obj = obj[args[i]];
  }
  return true;
}

var test = {level1:{level2:{level3:'level3'}} };

checkNested(test, 'level1', 'level2', 'level3'); // true
checkNested(test, 'level1', 'level2', 'foo'); // false
```

Comment: [Please don't copy and paste answers, instead reference them.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2631198/1293700)